# Efficiently treating functions in C/C++ called a million times

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, optimization

I'm new both to C and stackoverflow for programming questions. I've done a bit of googling about my question and I haven't been able to turn up information directly addressing this question. However, I also may just be so new to the subject that I'm not sure what terms are even appropriate to search for. So my apologies if this is a commonly asked question.

My program is implementing a scientific computation. In particular, it mostly involves taking given coordinates and given forces and updating everything based on a series of computations. To get results, I run through everything about a million times, so I'm concerned about making it as efficient as possible. In particular I've found that I have 3 types of variables

1. Variables that are constant and do not change
2. Temporarily variables that change from iteration to iteration
   and just are used as place holders in calculations
3. Data that is altered each iteration and then is carried through
   to the next

What is the most efficient ways to declare these different variables? In my naivety I am tempted to declare everything as global variables, I'm pretty sure this could make sense for variables of type (1) and (3). However for type (2) I'm unsure. If I call a function a million times and every time it is called in initializes a temporary variable, does this waste more time than if I have a global temp value that it alters instead?

Comment: Seems to me like you could try both of these options yourself and benchmark the results, you'd get a definitive answer.

Comment: What about posting some real code?

Comment: Whatever performance problems you are facing are most probably not in how you store your variables, nor on how you call your functions.  This would be the case if you threw a profiler on your code, and found that every single one of your, say, 1000 lines of code takes roughly one thousandth of the total run time.  But in all likelihood, that will not be the case.  So, use a profiler to pinpoint the bottleneck, and fix **that part only**.

Comment: try to limit the lifetime of variable to "just enough"

Comment: Suggestion: you are probably focusing on the wrong thing. How/where you declare variables can have performance impacts but is unlikely to be the dominate performance factor in the situation you have described. Unless you have specific reason to think it is.

Comment: Have you actually run your code and discovered it's too slow, or are you simply *anticipating* a problem? Computers are *extremely* fast these days, millions of computations aren't usually a problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom. I converted it from a MATLAB code. My simulations took ~30 days on my schools cluster. The C code is 6 times faster, still longer than I would like. I have to solve a bunch of fluid equations, so it is computationally expensive

Answer (score 3):

> If I call a function a million times and every time it is called in
>   initializes a temporary variable, does this waste more time than if I
>   have a global temp value that it alters instead?

No, it's even likely that the opposite is true. A temporary variable is created on the stack.

**Allocating a stack variable has no performance cost**
When the function is called, the stack pointer has to be moved anyway, to make room for the function arguments and other things. Now if an additional variable has to be allocated, all that has to be done is to increase the amount the stack pointer moves.
Unlike as with Java, you can leave a variable uninitialized, and store the final value directly when needed, such that there is no initialisation cost.

[**Locality of reference**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)
is also better, when you use a stack variable. This means the values the function uses are closer to each other, and this helps the processor to cache the data more efficiently. The cache is organized in lines of typically 64 bytes, that means two 32bit values that are adjacent to each other are more efficient than two scattered ones.
Spatial locality is especially important when paging occurs, because loading a page from permanent storage has a *huge* performance cost. Therefore it is better to have all the variables needed at a certain time stored close together, such that they fit into one page.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know enough about programming to understand the stack details, but I'll take your word for it and initialize them inside the functions

Comment: Thanks for believing me :-) , but keep in mind that optimisations always have to be tested when everything is finished, to know what difference (if any at all) they make.

Comment: Allocating a stack variable has no performaance cost, **but initializing it does**.  If he is going to initialize *several local variables*, but just once before calling the function (global vars in life, but local in scope) he has the option to *declare them as `static` inside the function body*.  He'll initialize them once and use many times, without the risk of being seen elsewhere.  Indeed, that's the reason to not initialize by default local variables.

Comment: The processor doesn't cache data based on spatial locality.  It uses a hash table, so the data can be spread.   It is **locality in time** what does data to remain in the cache.  If you access the same data soon after last use, it's most probable that it will be still present in the cache than not. Cache uses normally some LRU algorithm (least recently used) to replace the data in the cache.

Comment: By the way, spatial locality is important in instruction cache.  If the code of a loop is completely cached, you'll use the cache for all the execution of the loop.  This has to do with the secuential access done by the cpu to execute instructions.  But data is not subject to this same problem.

Comment: @LuisColorado, thanks for trying to improve my answer, but this was too much. I tried to address some points you edited in myself.

Comment: Ok, well.  Do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, storing the variable as global or local should not change anything if you call your function inside a loop. Actually, the assembly code should most likely be the same (`sub esp, SomeValue`) ; the only difference being `SomeValue` that could change a bit ; which does not change anything to the delay ; to the clock cycle precision.

Actually, setting the variable as global could even make your program run slower, as the compiler will be less able to understand your code and optimize it.

So, if you call your function inside a loop, do not bother with global vs. local and just go the usual way: variables as local as possible.

However, if your million calls are recursive calls, then memory is scarce and you should do your best to save it, and then should go for the global way.

Anyway, you most likely have much better optimizations waiting to be made somewhere in your code !

Comment: Consider that optimization can even turn a local variable into global or the opposite (or even reserve a cpu register for it, leading to a non-memory-at-all variable)

Answer (score 2):

Type 1 variables should be global

const double ABC = 1.234567;

The const is important for performance.

Type 3 can't be global. They need to be passed in each function call

```
void f1(double x)
{
    x = x + ABC;
    f2(x);
}
```

In case you need f2 to change x and get a changed value back use a reference instead:

```
void f1(double& x)
{
    x = x + ABC;
    f2(x);
}
```

Type 2 shall just be local in the functions:

```
void f1(double x)
{
    double y;
    x = x + ABC;
    f2(x);
}
```

Be sure to check the compilers optimization flags to get best performance.

Comment: What does **Type 1** variables mean?  What happened to **Type 2** ???  A `const double ABC` can be handled as a simple value if you never use a reference to it (in its scope).  This is exactly the performance you gain in case the compiler takes it into account.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about two differentiated concepts in C language:  extent and scope.

- **Extent** has to do with the extent of time the variable is going to last.  Global variables have always **global extent**, it means that they last from program beginning to program end, retaining their values from assignment to assignment during the whole program life.  Local variables have normally **local extent**, that means that variable is created/allocated at the point of its definition, and its life extends to the end of the inner block containing it.  Normally, compilers advance the stack pointer register at each function/block entry call by a fixed amount depending on the local storage of the block and the sizes and the number of parameters (in case of function blocks), so adding a local variable only changes the constant value to be added to SP register resulting in no extra execution penalty.  This is also the reason for local variables not being initialized on entry.
- **Scope** has to do with the visibility of the variable.  There are three different scopes for every object: **Global scope** means a variable can be accessed everywhere in the program;  **File scope** means a variable is only visible inside the file module that defines it, but not elsewhere, and; **Local scope** means a variable is visible from the point of declaration up to the end of the block. For global scope, you always have its name available to allow you to reference it.  In the opposite, local scope means a variable name is only available in the inner block containing its declaration (this is, the inner pair of `{` and `}` where the object is defined)

When you use the word `static`, it means two things, depending on where you are using it:

- If you use it outside any blocks, `static` means **file scope** (as oppossed to `extern` that means global program scope) By default, variables (and data) are file scope and functions (and code) are global scope (with functions, you have to use `static` to make them visible only inside the file of declaration).  With file scope, the variables are only visible inside the file where it's declared, but it has also global extent.  All objects defined outside any block (at the file level) have global extent (they exist from program start to program end)
- If you use `static` inside a block, it means this variable has local scope but it has global extent.  If you use `extern` inside a block, it means the object is defined this way, but elsewhere (it has global extent and scope, and I want to use it locally)

Just to complete, the appearance of `extern` doesn't make the compiler to allocate a variable, it only informs it that there's a variable (defined elsewhere, with global scope and extent) that has this type and name and can be accessed from here on, locally (or file scope, if used outside any block)  You'll have to put a declaration somewhere (in other file, or in this) without the word `extern` to make the compiler to allocate space for it.  For a program global variable, you have to define it twice (one with `extern` keyword and a definition without it ---and possibly an initializer) in the file where it actually resides, and be declared `extern` in all other files that are going to use it.

### EDIT

For variables that do not change during the lifetime of the program, it's best to define them as `const`.  This way, you allow the compiler to remember the constant value and to use its value instead of making references to it all around the program.  There is a large benefit in making a global value a `const`.  `const`s aren't even allocated memory, if you never use them by reference (through the `&` operator).

Answer (score 0):

First, don't go guessing what the problem is (that's what you're doing :)

Second, let the running program tell you what takes time.
In your comment, you said it takes many hours.
The method I use is to run it under a debugger, interrupt it, and see what it's doing.
If you do this several times, you will see that the interrupts are strongly drawn to the problem.

Do this with compiler optimization *off*. When you've made it as fast as you can, then turn on the compiler's optimizer.
If you've got silly stuff in there that you need to clean out, the optimizer won't clean it out for you. It will only make it harder to find.

[*This post*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262) shows some of my experience using this with scientific software.
It also gives the statistical justification why the method is so effective.

Things I've found in the past are spending a large fraction of those hours a) calling functions like `exp` or `log` over and over with same or almost-same arguments, b) calling general-purpose functions like matrix-multiply or cholesky transform which might be replaced with specialized routines.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely look into this. Yes indeed, the majority of the time is taken with the actual computation of my fluid solver which has many calls to Sinh and logs. I've spent a while carefully pre-calculating any expressions that show up more than once. With this specific part I'm at the extent of my knowledge of how to even try to speed up that part. So now I'm looking at the rest...

Comment: @Fractal20: I take my problem of interest and run it through a code-generator to make a problem-specific C program, which I then compile and link into my main program. That way no time is spent in superstructure. Then in place of calls to `exp` (for example) I have statics that remember the prior value of the argument and result to `exp`, and call a wrapper `exp_cached` which basically memoizes the function. This saved *big-time*, because lots of the calls were with arguments that change seldom or never. But again, first let the samples indicate it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> If I call a function a million times and every time it is called in
>   initializes a temporary variable, does this waste more time than if I
>   have a global temp value that it alters instead?

Not necessarily, because an optimizing compiler can put these variables directly into registers, instead of using even the stack. **Also the global temp value can be stored in a register**, as shown in below. In some architectures, such as x64, which has plenty of registers, one can hint the compiler to allocate both constants and other variables permanently to some registers.

Sufficiently small data could be similarly placed on xmm0..xmm7.

```
register long int a __asm__("r14");

int foo(int b)
{
    a = b * 2 + a;
    return a;
}

int bar(int c)
{
    a = a * 5 - c;
    return a;
}

int init(int i) { a = i; }
```

---

```
// in a separate file
int main(){
  init(3);
  printf("%d %d\n", foo(1), bar(2));
}
```

The disassembly shows, that the "global" variable is indeed stored into a register, allocated only once in `main`

```
foo:  leal (%rdi,%rdi), %eax
      cltq
      addq %r14, %rax
      movq %rax, %r14
      ret

bar:  leaq (%r14,%r14,2), %rax
      movslq %edi, %rdi
      subq %rdi, %rax
      movq %rax, %r14
      ret

main:  ...
      movl $3, %r14d
```